# WPF Binding - Changing property on one object in collection and all the objects are changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

When I change value of textbox or checkbox it changes in every line. Whats wrong?
Here is an examplу: All checkboxes aren't checked. I click on one of them and all the other are now checked.

[image]

Here is the code:
[image]

[image]

Adding position method:
[image]

Comment: Can you show how are you adding items to `AutoTradingPositions` collection?

Comment: I added the pictire

Comment: In future questions, please copy-paste your code into the editor, rather than taking screenshots. It makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the below line

```cs
spotPosition = AutoTradingPositions.Where(position => 
                          position.PositionNumber == latestPositionNumber).First();
```

Where you are getting the same instance *(first item in the collection)* and adding the same as other items to the collection.

Comment: But it's a command to add a new position. It executes only if I press the round button with a '+' sign. When i click on a checkbox, it doesn't invoke this method.

Comment: Still, for the existing items in the collection, the instance is same. Which mean, if you change any of the property in one item, it will reflect in others as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how it workes yet, but i commented this sectinon and ran the application. And now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Object at `AutoTradingPositions[0]`, `AutoTradingPositions[1]`, `AutoTradingPositions[2]` .... are same because of above line of code. So, if you change any property value (`IsBought` in your case) at `AutoTradingPositions[0]` will be reflected on other items as well.